# APACHE - PHP Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php

So I'm getting this errorn when I try to access my test site while deployed on a CentOS based Apache web server:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /var/www/betadmin/src/AdminBundle/Twig/WidgetTwigExtension.php on line 234
```

Line 234 contains the following:

```
 if(empty($session->get('currency'))) {
```

Here is the whole code:

```
public function get_default_currency()
{
    $session = new Session();

    if(empty($session->get('currency'))) {

        $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByDefault();

        if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

            $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByName('EURO');
            if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByActive();
                if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                    $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByInactive();

                    if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                        //$currency = array ('currency' => 'None');
                        return 'None';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $session->set('currency', $currency);
    }

   return $session->get('currency');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact empty function does not accepts a evaluating a function return directly. Empty() is not a function of language, but a language construct.

Try :

```
public function get_default_currency()
{
    $session = new Session();
    $ret = $session->get('currency');
    if(empty($ret)) {

        $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByDefault();

        if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

            $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByName('EURO');
            if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByActive();
            if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                $currency = $this->currencyService->findOneByInactive();

                if(!$currency instanceof Currency) {

                    //$currency = array ('currency' => 'None');
                    return 'None';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $session->set('currency', $currency);
}

   return $session->get('currency');
}
```

Comment: It's solved now. But it throws another error (unrelated to this one).
Thanks man.. :)